# React-Navigation back button takes me to the initial screen rather then the previously visited screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have a top level stack navigator

```
export const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
MainScreen: {
screen: MainScreen,
navigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    header: null,
},
},
Forgot: {
screen: forgot,
navigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
},
},
RegisterRouter: {
screen: RegisterRouter,
navigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
},  
....

class AppWithNavigationState extends React.Component {
 render() {
 const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
return (
  <RootNavigator
    navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch,
      state: nav,
      addListener,
    })}
  />
);
}
}
```

the registerRouter is another stack navigator

```
const RegisterRouter = StackNavigator({
Register: {
    screen: Register,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Registration',
        gesturesEnabled: false
    }
},
PersonalInfo: {
    screen: PersonalInfo,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'About you',
        gesturesEnabled: false
    }
},
PickPackage: {
    screen: PickPackage,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Packages',
        gesturesEnabled: false
    }`
```

however, where ever I press the back button I get returned to MainScreen rather than the previous screen.

I call the navigation as follows

```
onRegisterPress() {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('RegisterRouter');
}
<Button onPress={this.onRegisterPress.bind(this)} >
     Register
</Button>
```

I also call it inside of action creators as follows

```
const navToQuestionaire = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'PersonalInfo',
});
dispatch(navToQuestionaire);`
```

I do not want to manually use headerleft inside navigation options I just want it to navigate normally i.e go back to the previously visited screen. Thank you very much in advance for the help~

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my navigation options were blocking the headers for the sub routes, therefore the back button was always associated with the Root Navigator so it would always go back there.

Comment: Can you explain how you fixed this?  I am seeing the same issue

Comment: make sure the back button you have corresponds to your navigator. If you have navigators on top of each other (nested) there’s a high probability of this happening.

Comment: Yes, my stack navigator is nested.  Looks like this:  Drawer > Tab > Stack.  When in the stack, back button will go to Tab for some reason.  How do I make sure the back button corresponds to the stack?

Comment: thats strange, it should be the stack by default. try disabling the back button for tab in the navigationoptions